Mesh Severely Corrupted After Sculpting Operations - Any Way to Recover?
I was working on a sculpt in Blender (version 4.2) when I encountered a significant issue. While sculpting, I started noticing that my mesh was losing its structure—certain parts were thinning out or even losing thickness entirely. It felt like trying to sculpt with a completely deflated balloon. In an attempt to resolve this, I tried selecting the clean parts of the mesh, inverting the selection, and deleting the rest, but this didn’t help. Instead, the mesh became heavily corrupted, with large portions missing or severely fragmented, as shown in the attached image.

Although I’m not a complete beginner I’ve never learned how to recover from a situation like this. Tools like Draw and Clay Strips only seem to make the problem worse, Smooth neither.
Is there any way to salvage this mesh, or do I need to start over? Are there specific tools or techniques for fixing this type of severe corruption during sculpting? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
I understand this question might seem basic and could be a duplicate. I’ve searched but couldn’t find anything that addresses my specific issue.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

The problem is that you were voxel remeshing at too low of a resolution for too thin of a mesh. It always does worse with meshes that have to little volume. By "low resolution" I mean too big. Too much space. Unfortunately you won't be able to recover past whatever undo step you have still in memory.
